# Android Studio ')' expected

Tags: java, android

I have problem in the following line

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text);
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.purplesmile.vremenskaprognozasrbija;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_t))
                .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.error_massages))
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: typo: `setPositiveButton` has an missing closing `)` - closing...

Comment: @Dragi Dragi: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This code seems to be working for me. Could you try if this helps?

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_t))
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_t))
            .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.error_massages))
            .setPositiveButton(
                    context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already try that, and get error “cannot resolve method “ 'setPositiveButton (java.lang.String)'

Comment: Sorry.I just get 5 more errors

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Could you please elaborate on the error messages?

Comment: Cannot resolve dialog interface, except   (on the end});

Comment: Try importing `android.content.DialogInterface`. If it doesn't work, could you post the latest code that you are using?

Comment: I resolve dialog interface

Comment: The only problem with end "});", error "expecting")".... Thank you for petient, and please, sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Could you post the latest code because it is hard to figure out what's going wrong without it.

Comment: import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_t))

Comment: .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_t))
                .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.error_massages))
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                    }
                });

Answer (score 3):

Close the braces as shown below:

Change

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text);
```

to

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add an extra `)` to expression.

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text);
```

must be

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text));
```

As documentation says you must also specify `OnClickButtonListener` for this method.

declaration

```
public AlertDialog.Builder  setPositiveButton (CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

example

```
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_btn_text), new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
         // TO DO: Paste the code wich will execute when the positive button pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: @Dragi Dragi: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you're using Studio as IDE (if not move to Android Studio immediately). If so, try to use Auto Completion feature available in it to avoid such simple mistakes. See http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html